# Вопрос по Pandas Dataframe в Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Только начал изучать Python. Возник вопрос по pandas DataFrame.
Следующий код исполняется:

```
data['Weight'][5]
```

А вот такой ни в какую не исполняется:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(data['Weight'][i])
```

Ошибку выдает такую:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясните новичку пожалуйста, почему так происходит?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста, ошибку в виде текста, так гораздо проще читать и  по тексту работает поиск

Answer (score 2):

Это значит, что в вашем DataFrame не существует строки с индексом `0`.

Пример:

```
In [35]: df
Out[35]:
    Weight
5      100          # NOTE: индексирование начинается с 5
6      101
7      102
8      103
9      104
10     105

In [36]: df['Weight'][5]
Out[36]: 100

In [37]: df['Weight'][0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-1e19d5ad0ef3> in <module>()
----> 1 df['Weight'][0]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    765         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    766         try:
--> 767             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    768
    769             if not is_scalar(result):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   3116         try:
   3117             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 3118                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   3119         except KeyError as e1:
   3120             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer', 'boolean']:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

В Pandas не рекомендуют пользоваться двойным индексированием - вместо этого лучше воспользоваться методами `.loc[]` / `.iloc[]` / `.at[]` / `.iat[]`:

индексирование по порядковым номерам:

```
In [55]: df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('Weight')]
Out[55]: 100
```

индексирование по именам / значениям:

```
In [56]: df.loc[df.index[0], 'Weight']
Out[56]: 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Элемент `data['Weight'][5]` у вас есть. Но в цикле вы хотите печатать элементы

```
data['Weight'][0]
data['Weight'][1]
data['Weight'][2]
data['Weight'][3]
data['Weight'][4]
```

и какой-то из них не существует.